# Dart compiled to javascript and dart:svg interop

Tags: javascript, svg, dart

I'm experimenting with svg and got this code in dart:

```
num sw = 1.0; // stroke width
final PathElement path = new PathElement();
updatePath(num w, num h){
    final hsw = sw/2.0;
    w -= sw;
    h -= sw;
    var p1 = path.createSvgPathSegMovetoRel(hsw, hsw);
    var p2 = path.createSvgPathSegLinetoRel(w  , h);
    var p3 = path.createSvgPathSegLinetoRel(0.0,-h);
    var p4 = path.createSvgPathSegLinetoRel(-w , h);
    var p5 = path.createSvgPathSegClosePath();
    path.pathSegList
      ..clear()
      ..appendItem(p1)
      ..appendItem(p2)
      ..appendItem(p3)
      ..appendItem(p4)
      ..appendItem(p3)
      ..appendItem(p5);
  }
```

This runs fine in Dartium.
If I compile the project to javascript so it can run in normal Chrome (or another browser)
I get this compiler vomit:

```
AW:{
"":"tp;TJ:pathSegList=",
l2:[function(a){return a.createSVGPathSegClosePath()},"call$0","gS1",0,0,null],
tH:[function(a,b,c){return a.createSVGPathSegLinetoRel(b,c)},"call$2","guC",4,0,null,20,305],
zr:[function(a,b,c){return a.createSVGPathSegMovetoRel(b,c)},"call$2","gd2",4,0,null,20,305],
$isGv:true,
"%":"SVGPathElement"}
```

Annddd... that goes boom with

```
TypeError: Illegal invocation at AW.zr (http:/…gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:1358:94", message: "Illegal invocation"
```

Now this `createSVGPathSegMovetoRel` on the svg:path element is a native function, and there's lots of questions on stackoverflow that have `TypeError: Illegal invocation` and so far as I can tell it's all about calling the function on the wrong `this`.
Chrome doesn't like that...

I know the dart:svg package is experimental, but I'd like to get this to work with the svg API, preferably without manually creating the path data string and setting it via the `d` attribute.

Is there a trick I can use?

Full code is at: https://github.com/ReSc/gotrans

Here's the debug version of the generated javascript:

```
 PathElement: {
    "": "GraphicsElement;pathSegList=",
    createSvgPathSegClosePath$0: [function(receiver) {
      return receiver.createSVGPathSegClosePath();
    }, "call$0", "get$createSvgPathSegClosePath", 0, 0, null],
    createSvgPathSegLinetoRel$2: [function(receiver, x, y) {
      return receiver.createSVGPathSegLinetoRel(x, y);
    }, "call$2", "get$createSvgPathSegLinetoRel", 4, 0, null, 20, 305],
    createSvgPathSegMovetoRel$2: [function(receiver, x, y) {
      return receiver.createSVGPathSegMovetoRel(x, y);
    }, "call$2", "get$createSvgPathSegMovetoRel", 4, 0, null, 20, 305],
    $isInterceptor: true,
    "%": "SVGPathElement"
  }
```

and the error in debug mode:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/dart: "http###127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart". gotrans.html:11
Uncaught Error: Error: Illegal invocation gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:15435
Stack Trace: 
TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at PathElement.createSvgPathSegMovetoRel$2 (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:14437:23)
    at SceneGraph.build$0 (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:15477:19)
    at GoTransViewPort.GoTransViewPort$created$0 (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:15769:10)
    at _callConstructor_closure.GoTransViewPort.static.GoTransViewPort$created [as constructor_0] (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:15787:35)
    at _callConstructor_closure.call$1 (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:14224:19)
    at invokeClosure_closure0.call$0 (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:3493:29)
    at _IsolateContext.eval$1 (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:1279:23)
    at dart._callInIsolate (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:1059:26)
    at invokeClosure (http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:2369:16)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3030/gotrans/build/gotrans.html_bootstrap.dart.js:2386:108
```

the websocket server is in go for completeness:

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket"
    "github.com/codegangsta/martini"
    "time"
)

type (
    Move struct {
        OpCode string  `json:"opcode"`
        Id     string  `json:"id"`
        X      float64 `json:"x"`
        Y      float64 `json:"y"`
    }
)

func main() {
    m := martini.Classic()
    m.Get("/updates", websocket.Handler(Push).ServeHTTP)
    m.Run()
}

func Push(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    defer ws.Close()

    keepalive := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Second)
    defer keepalive.Stop()

    shutdown := make(chan bool)
    defer close(shutdown)

    updates := make(chan *Move)
    defer close(updates)

    go func() {
        id := "eq_0_0"
        x := 0.0
        y := 0.0
        incx := 10.0
        incy := 10.0
        for {
            if x > 200 {
                incx = -3.1
            }
            if x < 0.0 {
                incx = 9.2
            }
            if y > 200 {
                incy = -7.1
            }
            if y < 0.0 {
                incy = 5.1
            }
            x += incx
            y += incy
            select {
            case <-shutdown:
                return
            case <-time.After(200 * time.Millisecond):
                select {
                case updates <- &Move{OpCode: "move", Id: id, X: x, Y: y}:
                }
            }
        }

    }()

    for {
        select {
        case update, ok := <-updates:
            if ok {
                err := websocket.JSON.Send(ws, update)
                if err != nil {
                    return
                }
            }
        case <-keepalive.C:
            err := websocket.Message.Send(ws, "keepalive")
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
        case <-shutdown:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please build with `pub build --mode=debug` and post the error message again to get proper class/method names.

Comment: full code is on https://github.com/ReSc/gotrans/

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I dont believe that dart2js likes having inline dart scripts in your HTML code. Perhaps try moving this: `<script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>` into its own file?